# history.push() does not updates browser's url

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-router-v4

```
<div key={id} onClick={() => clicked(id)}>{name}</div>
```

In this clicked function is called.

```
const clicked = (id) => {
    history.push(`/user_dashboard/projects/${id}/designs`);
}
```

this is matched with the routes

```
<PrivateRoute path={match.url + '/:id/designs'} exact component={Designs} />
```

I have a route file with this route which opens dashboard with all the user projects

```
<PrivateRoute path='/user_dashboard/projects' exact component={Dashboard} />
```

In Dashboard it shows a toolbar with all the projects and if a user clicks any of the project it shows related designs corresponding to that project.

```
<Toolbar />
<PrivateRoute path={match.url} exact component={Projects} />
<PrivateRoute path={match.url + '/:id/designs'} exact component={Designs} />
```

I need to keep toolbar fixed in both the routes.What can I do?
Let me know if you find any mistake.

Comment: Please explain your problem in more detail. How have you defined history. A demo of your issue would be great

Comment: Yes, I have defined history in a const createHistory = require('history').createBrowserHistory;

Comment: I have added more details, Please check.

Comment: How have your defined Your Router, that piece of information is important. Also a demo reproduction your issue will help provide  a solutions. As of now people will just be firing arrows in the dark

Comment: I found the error, it was "exact" in the route that was creating a fuss. Removing it from the Designs Route worked. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Link` from `react-router-dom` instead of programmatically updating the URL.

```
<Link to={`/user_dashboard/projects/${id}/designs`} key={id}>{name}</Link>
```

this will handle the url for you, under the hood it's an anchor tag.

You can learn more about it [here](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start)

Comment: It updated the URL but it does not render anything on the DOM. I have provided more details for my question, please check.

Comment: It would be helpful for better understanding and debugging if you can host the demo-able app on codesandbox or somewhere and share the link.

Comment: I found the error, it was "exact" in the route that was creating a fuss. Removing it from the Designs Route worked. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

First error I can see is you are not using string interpolation for path property, so it should be

```js
path={`${match.url}/:id/designs`}
```

I think you need to provide more details for us to properly help you out on this issue.

Comment: I have provided more details for my question, please check. what I did does the same work as your string interpolation solution.